# MsSql - Non-Clustered index on few tables

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

Let's consider three tables:

```
 - User[Id, Name]
 - UserAddress[UserId, Value]
 - UserInfor[UserId, CreatedDate]
```

And simple query:

```
Select u.id, u.name, ua.Value
From [User] u
    INNER JOIN UserAddress ua on ua.UserId = u.Id
    INNER JOIN UserInfo ui on ui.UserId = u.Id
WHERE ui.CreatedDate > @someDate
```

What is the best way to optimize this query?
Is it possible to create a non-clustered index on three tables? I have an idea to create a clustered view. Is it ok? Are any pitfalls?

Comment: *"Is it possible to create a non-clustered index on three tables"* A table can have as many (or as few) non-clustered indexes as you want; it's only Clustered Indexes that are limited to 1 per table.

Comment: I mean that this index should depend on three tables. Smth like:
`INDEX ON tables[User, UserAddress, UserInfo] ([User.Id, UserInfo.CreatedDate]...)`

Comment: In order to have only one `Index Seek` or `Index Scan` without `Merge Join` or `Key Lookup`

Comment: An index belongs to a **single** object, not many. You'll need indexes on  each of the tables.

Comment: What about `clustered view`? It allows combining few tables into one index

Comment: You can create an index on a view, yes. The `VIEW` **must** be Schema Bound, and must have a unique clustered index before you can then add further nonclustered indexes to it.

Comment: Why would CreatedDate for a User exist in a table other than User? And given the names of your tables, why would "optimizing" this produce any significant benefit to your overall system? Are there pitfalls? Yes - every index requires processing time to maintain during DML. Every index requires space. Indexes often need additional periodic maintenance (like de-fragmenting). There is a cost to the choices you make - which you pay at different times and in different ways.

Comment: These tables are just an example.